# Insert a specific string instead of tabs or spaces in gVim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Since I'm working with LaTeX documents in vim, I want to be able to insert `\quad` instead of a tab space whenever I press tab (instead of having to replace/insert them manually). Is there any setting that could do this? If not, are there any plugins that work like this?

Comment: How about `inoremap <Tab> \quad`? To make it specific to LaTeX documents, you can make an autocmd like `autocmd FileType tex inoremap <buffer> <Tab> \quad`.

Comment: Yes this works perfectly! I wasn't aware of ```inoremap```, so this hadn't even crossed my mind. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use `inoremap` to change `Tab` to `\quad` in insert mode, that means
that you lose the original `Tab` functionality...

This might be worth it if you're sure that you'll never want to use `Tab`, but
what will you do when you face a similar problem of wanting some
latex-specific text? You could try and find a second key to map... but each
addition will take up a new key that already had some function.

The way I would handle this would be to use `iabbrev` to map some unlikely
sequence of keys like `;q` to `\quad`:

```
iabbrev ;q \quad
```

This has the advantage that you can build up a whole set of insert mode
abbreviations, all consistently starting with `;` followed by a letter or two
that you can choose to be easily remembered. And you get to keep all the
original functionality.